# Are Arthur Holmes lecture series helpful for a beginner?

Tags: reference-request

Are Arthur Holmes lecture series helpful for a beginner? I have only read Plato's dialogues and have listened to Michael Sugrue's lectures, which are quite good but they don't cover all philosophers.

Comment: He's not my cup of tea, but he's clearly a knowledgeable fellow. Personally, I really recommend Vervaeke's 'Awakening From The Meaning Crisis' https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLND1JCRq8Vuh3f0P5qjrSdb5eC1ZfZwWJ because it presents the history of philosophy not as a kind of stamp-collecting like Bertrand Russell does, but as progressive development around core drivers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.